# How to keep a value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

After doing an async $.ajax call, I need to highlight the table cell that was updated.
Right now I'm using $td in the global name space, which of course is a wrong idea.

Q: How do I keep the value of $td when the jqXHR is called back?  I think the answer has to do with closure, but I don't know.

```
var UpdateSort = function(ID,Sort){
    var jqXHR = $.ajax('Remote/Ajax.cfc', {
        data: {
        method:'UpdateSort'
        ,returnformat:'json'
        ,paramID:ID
        ,paramSort:Sort
    }
});
jqXHR.success(function(result){
    if (result.MSG == '') {
        $td.addClass('success');
    } else {
        $td.addClass('err');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closure *would* solve your problem. Give `UpdateSort` a reference to your `td` and define your success function there:

```
var UpdateSort = function(ID,Sort, td){
    var jqXHR = $.ajax('Remote/Ajax.cfc', {
        data: {
        method:'UpdateSort'
        ,returnformat:'json'
        ,paramID:ID
        ,paramSort:Sort
    }
    jqXHR.success(function(result){
        if (result.MSG == '') {
            td.addClass('success');
        } else {
            td.addClass('err');
        };
    });    
});
```

The value of `td` will be available to the function given to `jqXHR.success` after `UpdateSort` returns because it is in that function's [lexical scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_scope#Lexical_scoping).

Comment: Thanks lwburk.  Now I need to ask the same question, except add some complication to it.

Answer (score 2):

Just add it as an argument to your function.

```
var UpdateSort = function(ID,Sort,td){
    var jqXHR = $.ajax('Remote/Ajax.cfc', {
        data: {
        method:'UpdateSort'
          ,returnformat:'json'
          ,paramID:ID
          ,paramSort:Sort
        }
    }).success(function(result) {
      if (result.MSG == '') {
        td.addClass('success');
      } else {
        td.addClass('err');
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

add

```
var that;
```

to the top of your javascript file.
At the end of the succes function add:

```
this.td = $td;
that = this;
```

This will store your td file in a global variable 'that' which you can use when it's called back.
Take a look at this extremely useful document about variables : http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: The OP said that he's already doing that, but realises that he ought to avoid globals where possible and is therefore searching for an alternative.